# How to get image on an particular TextView String in android?

Tags: android, xml, json, imageview

I am building an android application where the data is parsing from the JSON volley library.

Now my need is that: there Should be an particular image in front of particular Text in an ListView.

For example, if the data parsing string is ice-cream, then there should be an Ice-cream image in front of it.

Here is the code I am using for parsing data:

```
package tabsswipe;

public class FragmentPlay extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

private Button ib;
private Calendar cal;
private int day;
private int month;
private int year;
private EditText et;



// Movies json url
private static final String url = "url";
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
private ListView listView;
private CustomListAdapter adapter;

String minstring, maxstring,finaldate;
EditText etxt1, etxt2;
String selItem, selItem2, selItem3, selItem4;
int ab, ba;
TextView tv1, tv2, txtsportname;
SeekBarWithTwoThumb swtt;

String firstlist;

public static ArrayList<String> array;
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int startYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int startMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int startDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
Spinner spnr;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {



    listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list1);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
                int Position, long offset) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Movie item = (Movie) adapter.getItem(Position);
            viewCategorysportdetails();
            // Intent intent = new Intent(rootView.getContext(),
            // SingleArticleAfrica.class);
            // single.title = item.getTitle();
            // single.author = item.getAuthor();
            // single.date = item.getDate();
            // single.featured_img = item.getFeatured_img();
            // single.content = item.getContent();
            // single.permalink = item.getPermalink();
            firstlist = item.getTitle();
            txtsportname.setText(firstlist);
            // Toast.makeText(getActivity(), firstlist,
            // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), movieList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    // Showing progress dialog before making http request
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.show();



    return rootView;
}

    @Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // Creating volley request obj
    JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    hidePDialog();

                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            Movie movie = new Movie();
                            movie.setTitle(obj.getString("foodname"));
                            // movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                            // movie.setRating(((Number) obj.get("rating"))
                            // .doubleValue());
                            // movie.setYear(obj.getInt("releaseYear"));

                            // adding movie to movies array
                            movieList.add(movie);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    // notifying list adapter about data changes
                    // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    hidePDialog();

                }
            });

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    hidePDialog();
}

private void hidePDialog() {
    if (pDialog != null) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        pDialog = null;
    }
}
}
```

Here is code where this parse value is add using CustomListAdapter:

```
package info.androidhive.customlistviewvolley.adater;

public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Activity activity;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<Movie> movieItems;
ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Movie> movieItems) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.movieItems = movieItems;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return movieItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int location) {
    return movieItems.get(location);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

    if (imageLoader == null)
        imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
    TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    TextView rating = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rating);
    //TextView genre = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.genre);
    TextView year = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.releaseYear);

    // getting movie data for the row
    Movie m = movieItems.get(position);

    // thumbnail image
    thumbNail.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);

    // title
    title.setText(m.getTitle());

    // rating
    rating.setText((m.getRating()));



    // release year
    year.setText(String.valueOf(m.getYear()));

    return convertView;
}

}
```

Here is XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="@color/list_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_row_selector" /> 


</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is ListAdapter XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/list_row_selector"
android:padding="8dp" >

<!-- Thumbnail Image -->
<com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
    android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />

<!-- Movie Title -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:textSize="@dimen/title"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<!-- Rating -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rating"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/title"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:textSize="@dimen/rating" />



<!-- Release Year -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/releaseYear"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:textColor="@color/year"
    android:textSize="@dimen/year" />
```

Comment: err...what is your problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
static List<String> foodnames = Arrays.asList((getResources().getStringArray(R.array.food_names)));

int key = foodnames.indexOf(getString(m.getFoodName())); 
String[] food_name_drawables = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.food_name_drawables);

ImageView foodname = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_foodname);
background.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(food_name_drawables[key]);
```

I think it should work...

Comment: Sorry I'm starting to answer here in SO in these days and I still don't know how to use it properly...

Comment: Thanks for such a nice support let me try it first!

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your need, but I'm not sure. Do you need to set as the background of the element view of the list an image representing the genre of the movie? Is that correct? If so:

If you take the infos from a server that you don't own, take a note of all the genres that the website uses, you put them in an array, and in the adapter depending on which genre is the movie of the list element, you change the background taking it from a drawable array. Let's say there are only 3 genres:
in xml:

```
<string-array name="movie_genres">
        <item>Dramatic</item>
        <item>Comedy</item>
        <item>Action</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name"movie_genres_drawables">
    <item>@drawable/dramatic_image</item>
    <item>@drawable/comedy_image</item>
    <item>@drawable/action_image</item>
</string-array>
```

then in the adapter:

```
static List<String> genres;
...
...

if (genres == null) {
genres = Arrays.asList((getResources().getStringArray(R.array.movie_genres)));
}

int key = genres.indexOf(getString(m.getGenre())); //Of course you should create this getter

String[] movie_genres_drawables = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.movie_genres_drawables);

ImageView background = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.background);
background.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(movie_genres_drawables[key]);
```

If you own the website with the movies archive, well you can take image directly from the server and put it on the list...

If I completely misunderstood your question, I'm sorry don't consider my answer at all. ;-)

Comment: No, sorry you are not getting my point. let me explain with an example. suppose - There is a keyword named as any "foodname" now when ice-cream (value of keyword) string is parse then ice-cream image should be displayed!(image is displaying from my project not from the server)

Comment: Does the string "foodname" contain only the food name or do you have to look for the foodname from within a longer phrase (i.e. the string is: "this ice-cream is very tasty")?

Comment: it's have only particular fix foodname like ice-cream, cake etc they are fix to the number 18 name.

Comment: In this case you can use the same method I posted you in my answer: you define 2 string arrays in xml (1 for the food names and the other with the drawables representing the images). In your adapter you take the key of the foodnames array matching the value of the food name of the element in the listview and you set the drawable as the image in the imageview. If it is not clear I will write you the code...

Comment: Thanks.... I know how to add the value to array in xml but how I cross check the name and set the image there can you please help me..